# Does ActiveRecord's find method automatically call to_i on its argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've come to the conclusion that ActiveRecord automatically calls to_i on its argument, but would appreciate if anybody can confirm, particularly through a reference to some documentation.

The way I came to the conclusion is best illustrated with the following code sample:

```
dest_task = WorkEffort.find(params[:task_dest_id])

params[:task_src_ids].split.each do |src_id|
    WorkEffort.find(src_id).move_to_child_of dest_task
end
```

When I ran the above only the record associated with the first src_id was processed although I knew the task_src_ids parameter contained something such as "78,79".  Thinking it through, find must be calling to_i on that string, which will ignore everything after the first non-digit and return 78.

If find wasn't calling to_i an error should have resulted, and I would have to call to_i explicitly.  I of course fixed the code by calling "split(',')" and now it processes multiple task_src_ids instead of just the one that comes before the first comma.

I know I've sort of answered this myself, but as a Ruby/Rails newbie am looking for confirmation, and a link to relevant documentation, plus I thought it could help out others in the future.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answering this with `activerecord-2.3.14`code, as you didn't specify a version.]

Ultimately, your value is going to be run through the `Quoting#quote` method. I've pasted the beginning of that here, and as you can see on the block starting at line 15 when your column type is an `int` it will end up calling `.to_i` on the value passed in.

```
  1 module ActiveRecord
  2   module ConnectionAdapters # :nodoc:
  3     module Quoting
  4       # Quotes the column value to help prevent
  5       # {SQL injection attacks}[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection].
  6       def quote(value, column = nil)
  7         # records are quoted as their primary key
  8         return value.quoted_id if value.respond_to?(:quoted_id)
  9           
 10         case value
 11           when String, ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars
 12             value = value.to_s
 13             if column && column.type == :binary && column.class.respond_to?(:string_to_binary)
 14               "'#{quote_string(column.class.string_to_binary(value))}'" # ' (for ruby-mode)
 15             elsif column && [:integer, :float].include?(column.type)
 16               value = column.type == :integer ? value.to_i : value.to_f
 17               value.to_s
 18             else
 19               "'#{quote_string(value)}'" # ' (for ruby-mode)
 20             end
```

Comment: Sorry about not including the version.  I am on Rails 2.3.11 so indeed very close.  And you've confirmed my conclusion.  By the way it's on line 16 not line 15 but I was disallowed from editing (and don't have edit privileges anyway) because the change wasn't enough characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure since when but now in Rails 6, `to_i` will be called automatically to the argument of `find` if the primary key of the Active Record is an integer which I think it is in most cases.

```
Product.find 10        # #<Product id: 10>
Product.find '10'      # #<Product id: 10>
Product.find '10-ten'  # #<Product id: 10>
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find